# eclipse plugin: get notification when selected project changed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I created a plugin which queries the selected project name & Path and displays it in a view at the startup. Here is my code on how i am querying for the selected project:

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
if (firstElement != null) {
    if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
        IProject project = (IProject) ((IAdaptable) firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
        IPath path = project.getFullPath();
        IPath location = project.getLocation();
    }
}
```

If project been changed (User selects any other project) or if the selected project been closed, how could i get a notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add a ISelectionListener by using the ISelectionService. There is also a nice article about that topic -> https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html

For project state changes you must add a IResourceChangeListener.

IWorkspace#addResourceChangeListener(IResourceChangeListener, int)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html

1) Create your own class implementing ISelectionChangedListener.

2) Call addSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener yourListener) on the selection provider you want to listen to:

```
  window.getSelectionService().addSelectionChangedListener(yourListener)
```

3) Process your selection events